# Swift - getDeliveredNotifications with completionHandler gives maximum 100 rows

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using getDeliveredNotifications to get the total count of notifications present in the notification center but I am getting only 100 notifications max. Counter stops after that.

'''

```
center.getDeliveredNotifications {  notifications in
    defer {
             semaphore.signal()
          }
          let count = notifications.count
          bestAttemptContent.badge = NSNumber(value: count + 1)
}
```

'''